# facet_grid labeller two lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use the `labeller` argument (and function) in `facet_grid` from the `ggplot2` package, so that multiple labels on one axis go under each other, rather than next to each other.

In the reproducible example below, I would like to get the label to say the company name with the sector underneath it in the same 'label box' i.e. 
'ABC Ltd\nAAAAAAAA' and 'DEF plc\nAAAAAAAA' and 'GHI LLP\nBBBBBBBBB' for the y axis facet labels. Ideally I would like to extend this for multiple  additional label descriptions that go underneath.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(date=Sys.Date()+seq(1000),
                  stock_px_1=100*cumprod(c(1,1+rnorm(999,0.00003,0.0004))),
                  stock_px_2=500*cumprod(c(1,1+rnorm(999,0.00001,0.0003))),
                  stock_px_3=10*cumprod(c(1,1+rnorm(999,0.00005,0.0005))))

stock_info <- data.frame(px_name=paste0('stock_px_',seq(3)),
                         stock_id=c('a1b2c3','d4e5f6','g7h8i9'),
                         sector=c('AAAAAAAA','AAAAAAAA','BBBBBBBBB'),
                         long_name=c('ABC Ltd','DEF plc','GHI LLP'))


dat_melted <- melt(dat,id.vars='date',variable.name='px_name',value.name='price')

joined_dat <- left_join(dat_melted,stock_info,by='px_name')

ggplot(joined_dat,aes(x=date,y=price,color=px_name))+
  geom_path()+
  facet_grid(long_name+sector~.,scales='free_y')+
  theme(strip.text.y=element_text(angle=0))+
  theme(legend.position='none')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `label_wrap_gen` option as follows

```
p <- sample_data %>%  ggplot(aes(x= Data, fill=Category)) + geom_density() + 
facet_grid(Name~Category, labeller = label_wrap_gen(width=10)) +
xlab("Data (Unit)")
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to simply add a new column that holds the combined labels:

```
joined_dat$combinedlabel=paste0(joined_dat$long_name,"\n",joined_dat$sector)
```

And then use said column to facet:

```
ggplot(joined_dat,aes(x=date,y=price,color=px_name))+
  geom_path()+
  facet_grid(combinedlabel~.,scales='free_y')+
  theme(strip.text.y=element_text(angle=0))+
  theme(legend.position='none')
```